# Android viewpager inside scrollview

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-scrollview

I have a viewpager and some buttons below viewpager. I added whole layout inside scrollview but due to viewpager the scrollview is not working. I tried many custom scrollview and viewpager classes but none worked. Is there any way to do it or do I have to use something else instead of viewpager. I'm using viewpager to display images.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private ViewPager viewPager;
    MyPagerAdapter adapter;
    private ArrayList<String> alName=new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        alName.add("http://i.imgur.com/wre2PiR.jpg");
        alName.add("http://i.imgur.com/BGGOhh1.jpg");
        alName.add("http://i.imgur.com/XGCLH1M.jpg");
        alName.add("http://i.imgur.com/kiPwp9I.jpg");
        adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(MainActivity.this, alName);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);


    } // onCreate ends

    public class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        private Context mContext;
        private ArrayList<String> arrayList=new ArrayList<String>();

        MyPagerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> jarr) {
            this.mContext = context;
            this.arrayList=jarr;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return arrayList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) {
            return view == o;
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            ImageView view = new ImageView(container.getContext());
            view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(arrayList.get(position)).into(view);
            container.addView(view);
            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            container.removeView((View) object);
        }

    }


}
```

Layout XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button 1"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button 2"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button 3"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button 4"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button 5"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button 6"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button 7"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button 8"/>




        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can custom the two components to solve this issue.

Custom ScrollView:

```
 @Override  
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {  

    switch (ev.getAction()) {    
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:    
            xDistance = yDistance = 0f;    
            xLast = ev.getX();    
            yLast = ev.getY();    
            break;    
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:    
            final float curX = ev.getX();    
            final float curY = ev.getY();    

            xDistance += Math.abs(curX - xLast);    
            yDistance += Math.abs(curY - yLast);    
            xLast = curX;    
            yLast = curY;    

            if(xDistance > yDistance){    
                return false;    
            }      
    }  

    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);    
}
```

Custom Viewpager:

```
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
{
  boolean ret = super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
   if(ret) 
  {
   requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
 }
return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you have set the scroll view as the parent layout , but if you want the content inside the pager to scroll create a fragment and set a scrolling layout to the fragment and set the fragment to the pager adapter , google provides a good example:

[Android Developers' Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)

hope this helps